# Upvotes and downvotes on question will be counted as Well Received Question [Socratic Badge]?

Tags: discussion

My understanding on **Socratic Badge** is that *asking a question which has only `Upvotes` in a day*.

Say, I've asked a question for which I have -

- equal number of `Upvotes` and `Downvotes`.
- More `Upvotes` and less `DownVotes` and vice versa.,

Will the question be considered as **Well received question** and counted for **Socratic Badge** under above scenarios?